# Knowing (rightaway) when google search result is based on previous search

Tags: google-search, privacy

It used to be that at the bottom of the webpage, one can see it written, whether the search results are  independent or based on your previous activity / search history.

It is the case (it seems) that Google Search results now mandate "scroll and load". I thus had to load 6 times before I can see whether the search results are based on my previous activity.

Is there a way to see whether the search results are based on previous activity, without additional page loads?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the information in the ellipsis (`...`) menu when searching, but you may need to scroll down to see the section:

[image: Not personalized. A result is only personalized when it seems helpful for you, based on your Google Account activity.]

You can also turn off personalized results in [your settings](https://myaccount.google.com/yourdata/search).

Comment: Doesn't seem to tell if the list is based on my activity. Or do you mean you have to click that **for each** every search result?

Comment: Yes, the information in the popup only applies to one search result. I don't see any other way to do this.